# How receive coordinates from the graph for all X range?

Tags: python, graph

I have plotted four points on the x-axis from 0 to 400 because i only knew 4 coordinates on the y-axis.
But I need to get the Y-coordinates for the entire X-axis, that is, for all 400 points. Does anyone know how easy it is to do this in Python?
[image]

Comment: Google "linear interpolation"

Comment: Yes, I did it, but the result was not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear interpolation works like this:

[image]

Notice that (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) is constant for all points in between.

Comment: Yes, I know it, thank you, in fact I have a graph that have much more than I provided in the example, so if I will make Linear interpolation for each segment it will take a long time

Comment: There is no way that is any faster.  It should do many thousands of points per second of run time

Comment: To calculate each interpolated point requires just one multiplication.  Perhaps 10 microseconds on any decent laptop.

Comment: "have much more"  How many points do you want to calculate?  There is no sense in calculating more points than your screen resolution - multiple points will end up on the same pixel.

Comment: " it will take a long time"  How long is a long time for you?  Linear interpolation will calculate a reasonable number of points in less time than the refresh rate of your display, so, if you use a decent plotting library the interpolated then the graph will appear instantly.

Comment: thank you, I will try implement again interpolation  and let you know)

Comment: it works and for big data, thank you!